# ngx-numeric-textbox align right

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm using ngx-numeric-textbox in Angular 6 App, and this work well, but by default the text is aligned at left and I want to align to right. I tried many ways in CSS but none works. How can I overwrite this so that it goes to the right instead? I'm using HTML and SASS...

This is my HTML:

```
 <ngx-numeric-textbox 
    name="inputPrecio" [min]="0" [max]="99999999" 
    [disabled]="false" [decimals]="0" [format]="'$ 0,0'"
[placeholder]="'Ingrese un precio'" 
    [rangeValidation]="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="item.precio" 
    (ngModelChange)="calcularSubtotal()"
    required>
    </ngx-numeric-textbox>
```

And this is my SASS:

```
ngx-numeric-textbox {
  &input {
    text-align: right !important;
  }
}
```

[image: deploy in firefox]

Comment: Did you try to add `::ng-deep` into your selector rule? i.e. `&::ng-deep input {...}` I think you are running into an issue with the encapsulation of styles.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, finally I solve this with your advice and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve this, adding ::ng-deep into the selector rule. This was an issue with the encapsulation of styles:

```
ngx-numeric-textbox {
  &::ng-deep input {
    text-align: right !important;
  }
}
```

[showing in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA8Pu.png)